# How to replace/change the array value with arrayobject value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

How to change the nested array object by array values in javascript.

I have array object `nestobj`  and array `arr`, in which if place and array matches then replace the value in javascript.

I need to know how to change the array object `nestobj` with same variable name

```
var nestobj =[
  {id:1, name: "xyz", place: "CH"},
  {id:2, name: "zen", place: "JP"},
  {id:3, name: "abc", place: "TH"},
  {id:4, name: "ram", place: "MY"},
  {id:5, name: "mike", place: "AU"},
]


var arr=[
  "JP:Japan",
  "CH:Chennai",
  "AU:Australia"
]


Expected Ouput
[
  {id:1, name: "xyz", place: "Chennai"},
  {id:2, name: "zen", place: "Japan"},
  {id:3, name: "abc", place: "TH"},
  {id:4, name: "ram", place: "MY"},
  {id:5, name: "mike", place: "Australia"},
]

arr.map(ii=>{
  var kv = ii.split(':');
  nestobj.map(e=>{
    if(e.place === kv[0]){
   return { 
 ...e,
 place: kv[1]
    }
else{
   ...e,
  place: e.place
  }
   }
  })

})

console.log(nestobj)
```

Comment: [The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).  This means you need to `arr = arr.map(...` and/or `nestobj = nestobj.map(...` because map does not replace values on the array its iterating.

Answer (score 1):

Does this what you mean?

```js
let nestobj =[
    {id:1, name: "xyz", place: "CH"},
    {id:2, name: "zen", place: "JP"},
    {id:3, name: "abc", place: "TH"},
    {id:4, name: "ram", place: "MY"},
    {id:5, name: "mike", place: "AU"},
  ]

  const arr=[
    "JP:Japan",
    "CH:Chennai",
    "AU:Australia",
  ]

  nestobj = nestobj.map((item, index) => {
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      const key = arr[i].split(":")[0]
      const value = arr[i].split(":")[1]

      if(item["place"] === key) {
        item["place"] = value
      }
    }
    return item
  })
  
  console.log(nestobj)
```

The new `nestobj` will be:

```
[
  {id:1, name: "xyz", place: "Chennai"},
  {id:2, name: "zen", place: "Japan"},
  {id:3, name: "abc", place: "TH"},
  {id:4, name: "ram", place: "MY"},
  {id:5, name: "mike", place: "Australia"},
]
```

I suggest you use `let` (for dynamic variables) and `const` (for static variables) to avoid [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

my way...

```js
const nestobj = 
  [ { id: 1, name: 'xyz',  place: 'CH' } 
  , { id: 2, name: 'zen',  place: 'JP' } 
  , { id: 3, name: 'abc',  place: 'TH' } 
  , { id: 4, name: 'ram',  place: 'MY' } 
  , { id: 5, name: 'mike', place: 'AU' } 
  ] 

const arr = [ 'JP:Japan', 'CH:Chennai', 'AU:Australia' ] 

const country =  Object.fromEntries(arr.map(e=>e.split(':')))

nestobj.forEach((e,i,a)=> { a[i].place =  country[e.place] ?? e.place })

console.log( nestobj )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0 }
```